# Assign JSON value to another key in the JSON

Tags: json

So I'm working on reducing redundancy in some code. I have access to changing the JSON file, but not the JS code that parses it.

As an example:

```
{ Cars:
    {Toyota:
        {Tercel:
            {years:[1999,2000,2001,2002...]
```

What I'm trying to see if it is possible, is to change the 'years' variable to be at a higher level, so it doesn't have to be repeated for every model.

Like this:

```
{ Cars:
    {years:[1999,2000,2001,2002...]
    {Toyota:
        {Tercel: 
            {years: this.parent.years}
```

Comment: json does not support this. Take a look at yaml if it works for your needs. Having said that it is better to avoid such complex notions in data format.

Comment: One option would be to describe your data in yaml, with the references it supports , and then convert to json before sending.  But I agree it's not really a good idea.  There's worse things than a little data duplication.